# VBA to copy two sheets together and get 100 copies

Tags: vba, worksheet

I have two template sheets (linked), I would like to create about 100 times of both, and rename them as per the list on sheet "Output-->>>" form cell A381. eg. tesco, tesco LL

The below code doesnt work, can anyone help please?

```
Sub makeSheets()
Dim sh1 As Worksheets, sh2 As Worksheet, c As Range
Set sh1 = Sheets(Array("Template", "Template LL"))
Set sh2 = Sheets("Output-->>>")
    For Each c In sh2.Range("A381", sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
        sh1.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value
    Next
End Sub
```

Many thanks

Comment: Start by fully qualifying your `Rows` reference:

`sh2.Cells(sh2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)`

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a good description of what happens when you run your code.